# Why does twist web suggest --listen instead of --port?

Tags: twisted

Twisted Python web suggests the listen option replaces the port option, but all the documentation seems to refer to the old option. Do they have any differences other than the name?

Comment: Do you mean `twist web`?  `twist` has neither option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twist web --ports` sets a single port for the server to listen on.

`twist web --listen` adds to a collection of ports for the server to listen on.

So, the difference is that the former only lets you configure a server listening on one port and the latter lets you configure a server listening on as many as you like.